# update_attributes within a block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update a model that has translated content through `globalize3`. To do so, I need to change the locale multiple times to update the model. However, the `update_attributes` method does not seem to accept a block as a parameter. Is there any other way that achieves the following?

```
Country.where(code: 'NLD').first_or_create.update_attributes do |country|
  I18n.locale = :en
  nld.name = 'Netherlands, The'

  I18n.locale = :nl
  nld.name = 'Nederland'
end
```

The reason that I am doing `first_or_create` followed by an `update_attributes` is that I want to be able to run my seed file multiple times and have the data updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G3 has `set_translations` method, so you can

```
Country.where(code: 'NLD').first_or_create.set_translations(
  :en => { :name => 'Netherlands, The' },
  :nl => { :name => 'Nederland' }
)
```